# Create data frame from patterns in a string from a file

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a very large file that has some sort of titles in the begginning, then a lot of data in eight columns but this data is not separated in a regular way by spaces (they decided to spit the columns separated by spaces but if some column breaks the "normal" size, the columns end up separated by more or less space characters.

What I did is, I can read the file using a connection and reading line by line using gsub by applying a certain regular expression, something like this:

```
conn <- file("my_file.dat", open="rt")
y <- gsub("a_ver_large_regexp", 
        "\\1, \\2, \\3, \\4, \\5, \\6, \\7, \\8", #the columns I want csv'd   
        perl = TRUE,
        readLines(conn, n=-1L))
```

then I end up with y, a vector of characters where I have each element in character class but at least now comma separated too.

Now I want to convert that y vector to a data frame, I suppose it could be somehow easy given that each element is an string but it has commas so I can read them easily, any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can't you use `read.csv/read.table` with `sep=","`

Comment: I don't think so, I tried, this comes out:

Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat difficult to try to write a solution when we cannot see for example `y` or the original data. However, I think that

```
as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(y, ",")))
```

might get you what you are after.